# Dual booting with SD card

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I'm trying to dual boot Linux Ubuntu to my HP Windows 10 laptop using an SD card, but I can't seem to figure it out. If anyone could help me figure this out that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Does your computer support booting from an SD card?

Comment: @David It doesn't have to be able to boot from the media where the system is installed as long as the ESP resides in a drive it can boot from. Assuming a preinstalled Windows the already existing ESP will be used. That said, installing any OS in a SD card is a very bad idea.

Comment: @David I don't know how to check that

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will try that, but since its 4am ill have to go find a USB stick in the morning

Comment: @David It reads exactly as the canonical duplicate. The destination media type is irrelevant.

Comment: According to the HP web site and forums it MIGHT if it is in the BIOS as an option to select it to boot. They say it is hit and miss.

Comment: @AdamWiesehuegel Are you trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows in an SD card -or- are you trying to use the SD as the installation media? Very different propositions! If the latter then Daivd is entirely right, you must be sure your machine CAN boot from an SD card, some do, most DON'T. If the former then, again, the media type isn't relevant but SDs are bad for that, slow and wear out quickly.